# Fluid Mechanics - Sources/Sinks/Streamlines

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image]

My doubt is regarding the last part.
How does one find the differential equation and then prove that they lie on the given surface?

I am aware of the method, by writing dx/u = dy/v (or its equivalent in cylindrical).
It's just that I am unable to get any answer.

Reference:
Part of this question has been asked here - [To find the velocity potential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527613/to-find-the-velocity-potential)

Answer (score 2):

The velocity field is given by $\mathbf{v} = - \nabla \phi$.  Using spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\varphi)$ where the polar angle $\theta$ is measured with respect to the $x$-axis we have

$$\mathbf{v} = -\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\mathbf{e}_r + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta}\mathbf{e}_\theta + \frac{1}{r \sin \theta}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \varphi}\right)$$

The potential, $\phi = mr^{-1} - Ur \cos \theta$, does not depend on the azimuthal angle $\varphi$, and the flow is axisymmetric with velocity components

$$v_r = - \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{m}{r}- U r \cos \theta \right) = \frac{m}{r^2}+ U \cos \theta, \\v_\theta = -\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\left(\frac{m}{r}- U r \cos \theta \right) = -U \sin \theta$$

For three-dimensional axisymmetric flow, the velocity components are related to the [streamfunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_stream_function), $\psi$, by

$$v_r = \frac{1}{r^2\sin \theta} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta}, \quad v_\theta =  -\frac{1}{r\sin \theta} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}$$

Hence,

$$\tag{1}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta} = r^2 \sin \theta \,v_r = m \sin \theta + U r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta,$$ $$\tag{2}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} = -r \sin \theta \,v_\theta  = Ur \sin^2 \theta$$

Integrating (1) (with respect to $\theta$) and (2) (with respect to $r$) we get we get $$\psi = -m \cos \theta + \frac{1}{2} U r^2 \sin^2 \theta + F(r), \\ \psi = \frac{1}{2} U r^2 \sin^2 \theta + G(\theta)$$

Comparing we see that $F(r) = 0$ and $G(\theta ) = - m \cos \theta$ and the stream function (up to an arbitrary constant) is

$$\psi = -m \cos \theta + \frac{1}{2} U r^2 \sin^2 \theta,$$

and streamlines lie on surfaces where $\psi = \text{constant}$, or equivalently, $ U r^2 \sin^2 \theta -2m \cos \theta= \text{constant}$.